# Excel combine cell content into an html code?

Tags: excel

Basically I have a html code in a cell which I'd like to pick out content from different cells in the same row.

This cell is C2;

```
<a href="/signup?name=A2&email=B2">Go</a>
```

Output would be;

```
<a href="/signup?name=James&email=james@email.com">Go</a>
```

So the A2 and B2 would be contents of their respective cells. Tried out a few things but kept getting errors, is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sure is possible! You just need to make it a **formula**.

```
="<a href=""/signup?name="&A2&"&email="&B2&""">Go</a>"
```

- Please note the `&` signs next to the cell addresses are different from the other ones. These are the glue that let you concatenate the cell values to the HTML text.
- Also note that wherever you had a double quote in the HTML code, you now have escaped double quotes.

Comment: Wow that worked great, thanks a lot!! I kept wrapping ="" around the code which kept returning an error, guess the double quotes was the issue..